# Remove the [optimal] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

#### UPDATE: burnination complete!

The [optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimal) tag does not sound useful as a stand-alone tag and should therefore be removed.

Comment: In other words, [optimal] doesn't seem to be the optimal tag for any of the questions on SO.

Comment: It cannot simply be burninated. The questions need to be cleaned up, possibly replacing [optimal] with another tag (e.g. [optimization]), or possibly closing the question.

Answer (score 15):

I agree as it is also quite subjective. Optimal can mean fastest, easiest to read, fewest lines, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Many questions currently tagged with [optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimal) are asking about optimization of some form, and therefore probably belong in [mathematical-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-optimization) or [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

Examples currently using [optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimal) that could fit under [mathematical-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-optimization):

- [Is there a case that a heuristic approach to be guaranteed to provide optimal solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782932/is-there-a-case-that-a-heuristic-approach-to-be-guaranteed-to-provide-optimal-so)
- [Path finding Algorithm - multiple tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870559/path-finding-algorithm-multiple-tasks)
- [Given multiple static data streams, how to design an optimal scheduling policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645753/given-multiple-static-data-streams-how-to-design-an-optimal-scheduling-policy)

Examples currently using [optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimal) that could fit under [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization):

- [Optimal 3D vertex patterns OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415154/optimal-3d-vertex-patterns-opengl)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758236/java-sieve-of-erathostenes-optimization
- [Too slow shortest path algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684607/too-slow-shortest-path-algorithm)

It seems to me that [optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimal) should be merged into these larger tags.

Answer (score 5):

Optimal is a matter of preference to the context. It's unclear as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to have an "optimal answer" for most questions, as "optimal" could describe an algorithm or code, but hardly the application. As such the "optimal" tag is not commonly used, and most ends in few answers. I believe it should be burninated as well.

Answer (score 0):

`[optimal]` is as useful as `[perfect]`. It's a superlative to strive for, but nothing one can achieve.

Comment: What you say might be true in real life, but not so in mathematics or computer science, where you can actually prove optimality properties within certain models.

Comment: @Niklas B: While true, stackoverflow is for the most part about practical software-development (i.e. the real life you mean, in some sense), and my answer was w.r.t. that. Computer Science (afair) and Maths have their own SO-instances. -- edit: IMHO; exceptions exist, but prove the rule.

Comment: So you're saying people shouldn't ask anymore "What's the best way to do this", because that does not exist? Disagree. I'm against the tag, but not for the reason stated here.

Comment: @FooBar: The typical "What's the best" question often provokes personal opinions. Answering with "The best" possible answer is only possible if you know the _whole_ system of the questioner, _and_ if _you_ know _all_ of the alternatives.

Comment: I agree. "What's the best" is primarily opinion based.